# How to find foreign key dependencies of a specific row?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table, TableA:

```
Id
1
2
3
...
```

And two other tables:

TableB:

```
Id, TableAId
1   1
2   1
```

TableC:

```
Id, TableAId
1,  1
2,  2
```

Where TableAId is a FK relationship with TableA.Id.

How do I determine that TableA, Id 1, has three rows pointing to it?  And that TableA, Id 2 has one row pointing to it?  And more specifically, how do I identify what those rows are? (their table name and Id)

Comment: Your goal is not entirely clear. Are you wanting to find the metadata to identify foreign key realtion ships between the tables, or are you wanting the TSql queries to find the data given that you already know the foreign key relationships ?

Comment: I am not interested in the metadata.  In my example I show how I am interested in determining the tables and specific rows that have dependencies on another specific row.  I would like to obtain that info without writing a (potentially) enormous select statement that joins every possible table together with the target table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views to generate select statements to display the rows in question.  I have only tested this against the tables provided in the question, but it could be expanded to work in cases where the keys are multiple columns.

```
declare @table_schema nvarchar(50) = 'dbo',
        @table_name nvarchar(50) = 'TableA',
        @id int = 1

select fk_col.TABLE_SCHEMA, fk_col.TABLE_NAME, fk_col.COLUMN_NAME, 
    'select * from ' + fk_col.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + fk_col.TABLE_NAME + ' t1 '
        + ' inner join ' + @table_schema + '.' + @table_name + ' t2 '
        + ' on t1.' + fk_col.COLUMN_NAME + ' = t2.' + pk_col.COLUMN_NAME
        + ' where t2.' + pk_col.COLUMN_NAME + ' = ' + cast(@id as nvarchar)

from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk

    join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE pk_col
        on pk.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = pk_col.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
        and pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk_col.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS fk 
        on pk.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = fk.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
        and pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME = fk.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME

    join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE fk_col
        on fk_col.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = fk.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
        and fk_col.CONSTRAINT_NAME = fk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

where pk.TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema 
    and pk.TABLE_NAME = @table_name
    and pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

The select statements generated:

```
select * from dbo.TableB t1  inner join dbo.TableA t2  on t1.TableAId = t2.Id where t2.Id = 1
select * from dbo.TableC t1  inner join dbo.TableA t2  on t1.TableAId = t2.Id where t2.Id = 1
```

and the query results:

```
Id          TableAId    Id
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           1           1

Id          TableAId    Id
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
```

Comment: Hi please could you give me the equivalent Mysql code.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have SQL on this computer so I can't give You exact code but here is the way you should go. Please, note that I will use SQL Server terminology.

I see no way to do this without dynamic sql, at least in SQL Server.

1. Create temporary table #t with columns `FK_TBL_NM`, `FK_CLMN_VAL`.
2. It should not be difficult to get all the fk relationships for pk of TableA:

   ```
   SELECT *  FROM sys.foreign_keys 
   WHERE referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableA')
   ```
3. Use a cursor to iterate thru the result of this query and for each generate and execute dynamic sql that will join `TableA` and table retrieved from cursor and returns `FK_TBL_NM` (TableB, TableC, ...) and value of fk column.
4. Insert the result into #t (it is tricky to get dynamic sql result into table but do a research on stackoverflow)

Now you have the table that contains one row for each row in `TableB`, `TableC`, ...

I know this is feasible because I wrote the code with similar logic for my current project at work just few days ago.

Note that you should probably make your code work with pk/fk with more that one column. Also there are different data types for columns. It complicates things a bit but it is possible.

Every step I listed above is not difficult to implement. However, if you have any difficulties, search on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out what FK relationships exist, you need to inspect the `sys` catalog views in SQL Server - something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableA')
```

This will list out all foreign key relationships that exist to `TableA`.

Once you have that information, it's a pretty simple JOIN between `TableA` and any of those other tables involved.

**Update:** once you know that e.g. `TableB` and `TableC` reference your `TableA`, you can find the depdendent rows with a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM dbo.TableC c
INNER JOIN dbo.TableA a ON a.ID = c.TableAID  -- or whatever column joins the tables.....
WHERE.......  -- possibly with a WHERE clause...
```

Comment: @KirkWoll: Yes, I know - but those depedencies at the data level only exist based on the schema! If you don't know **what** other table reference `TableA`, you have **no way** of finding out what **rows** from those other tables reference rows in your `TableA`

Comment: I *do* know the dependencies at the schema level.  But that does not tell me how to find the data dependencies.  How do I find the dependent *rows*?  And in practice I have about 20-30 tables all pointing to this table.  Creating that massive join is the only way?

Comment: @KirkWoll: how do you want to find data dependencies, if you don't know in which other tables those rows might be that reference your row in `TableA`??? You need **schema dependencies** first - **THEN** (and only THEN) can you look for data dependencies....

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.  I was hoping for something that would not require writing a massive select statement with an enormous number of joins.  For example, trying to *delete* a row that has such dependencies is a quick and easy way to find out the FKs that will be violated.  I was just hoping for something similar without actually having to attempt a delete.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I wouldn't know of any such "magical" way to just delete everything - unless you use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on your FK relationships, of course!

Comment: I wasn't hoping for a magical way to delete everything.  My point by mentioning a delete operation is that when you attempt to delete a row that has such dependencies you get an error indicating which FKs will be violated.  That error message is very useful and is basically what I am trying to get.  But I don't want to have to attempt a delete just to get it.

Comment: @KirkWoll: It is interesting way to go, but you can't rely on that because MSSQL will fail on first violated FK, and You will see only first table it relies on, not all tables and you asked for all tables/rows, right?

Comment: @Filip, so it's a bad solution for that reason too.  But it "feels" like this information should be readily and easily accessible.  But I guess not.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Unfortunately not, and trust me, the solution I gave You in answer below is not a short and easy task. I spent some time on it. If You do find better solution please share it here.

Comment: @KirkWoll - Nope. If you look at the query plan for a delete operation with multiple foreign keys you will see it constructs an execution plan with outer joins and an assert operator to validate the constraint. You'll need to do something similar with dynamic SQL. But probably you would want `UNION` rather than `OUTER JOIN` as you want to know **all** rows not just **any** row.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find perfect reusable answer for this so combining a few different answers I created a stored procedure to do the job.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETLINKEDKEYS 
    @PKTABLE_NAME varchar(32) 
    ,@PKTABLE_ID int 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @fkeys TABLE ( 
        [PKTABLE_QUALIFIER] varchar(32) 
        ,[PKTABLE_OWNER] varchar(3) 
        ,[PKTABLE_NAME] varchar(32) 
        ,[PKCOLUMN_NAME] varchar(32) 
        ,[FKTABLE_QUALIFIER] varchar(32) 
        ,[FKTABLE_OWNER] varchar(3) 
        ,[FKTABLE_NAME] varchar(32) 
        ,[FKCOLUMN_NAME] varchar(32) 
        ,[FKCOLUMN_PKNAME] varchar(32) 
        ,[KEY_SEQ] int 
        ,[UPDATE_RULE] int 
        ,[DELETE_RULE] int 
        ,[FK_NAME] varchar(64) 
        ,[PK_NAME] varchar(32) 
        ,[DEFERRABILITY] int 
    ); 

    INSERT INTO @fkeys 
        ([PKTABLE_QUALIFIER],[PKTABLE_OWNER],[PKTABLE_NAME],[PKCOLUMN_NAME],[FKTABLE_QUALIFIER],[FKTABLE_OWNER],[FKTABLE_NAME],[FKCOLUMN_NAME],[KEY_SEQ],[UPDATE_RULE],[DELETE_RULE],[FK_NAME],[PK_NAME],[DEFERRABILITY]) 
        EXEC sp_fkeys @PKTABLE_NAME; 

    UPDATE FK SET 
        [FKCOLUMN_PKNAME] = (SELECT [COLUMN_NAME] 
            FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[KEY_COLUMN_USAGE] 
            WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID([CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA] + '.' + QUOTENAME([CONSTRAINT_NAME])), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1 
            AND [TABLE_NAME] = FK.[FKTABLE_NAME]) 
    FROM @fkeys FK 

    DECLARE @StringTable TABLE ([ID] int IDENTITY(1, 1), [Query] varchar(max)); 

    INSERT INTO @StringTable 
    SELECT 
        'SELECT ''' + [PKTABLE_NAME] + ''' AS ''PrimaryTable'' ' + 
        ',''' + [PKCOLUMN_NAME] + ''' AS ''PrimaryTableColumn'' ' + 
        ',PT.[' + [PKCOLUMN_NAME] + '] AS ''PrimaryTableColumnID'' ' + 
        ',''' + [FKTABLE_NAME] + ''' AS ''ForeignTable'' ' + 
        ',''' + [FKCOLUMN_NAME] + ''' AS ''ForeignTableColumn'' ' + 
        ',FT.[' + [PKCOLUMN_NAME] + '] AS ''ForeignTableColumnID'' ' + 
        (CASE WHEN [FKCOLUMN_PKNAME] IS NULL THEN ',NULL' ELSE ',''' + [FKCOLUMN_PKNAME] + '''' END) + ' AS ''ForeignTablePrimaryColumn''' + 
        (CASE WHEN [FKCOLUMN_PKNAME] IS NULL THEN ',NULL' ELSE ',FT.[' + [FKCOLUMN_PKNAME] + ']' END) + ' AS ''ForeignTablePrimaryColumnID''' + 
        'FROM [' + [PKTABLE_NAME] + '] PT ' + 
        'JOIN [' + [FKTABLE_NAME] + '] FT ' + 
        'ON FT.[' + [FKCOLUMN_NAME] + '] = PT.[' + [PKCOLUMN_NAME] + '] ' + 
        'WHERE PT.[' + [PKCOLUMN_NAME] + '] = ' + CONVERT(varchar(16), @PKTABLE_ID) 
    FROM @fkeys; 

    DECLARE @matchTable TABLE ( 
        [PrimaryTable] varchar(32) 
        ,[PrimaryTableColumn] varchar(32) 
        ,[PrimaryTableColumnID] int 
        ,[ForeignTable] varchar(32) 
        ,[ForeignTableColumn] varchar(32) 
        ,[ForeignTableColumnID] int 
        ,[ForeignTablePrimaryColumn] varchar(32) 
        ,[ForeignTablePrimaryColumnID] int 
    ); 
    DECLARE @Count int = (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM @StringTable); 
    DECLARE @QueryString varchar(max); 

    WHILE @Count > 0 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 
            @QueryString = [Query] 
        FROM @StringTable WHERE [ID] = @Count; 

        INSERT INTO @matchTable 
        EXECUTE(@QueryString); 

        SET @Count = @Count - 1; 
    END 

    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM @matchTable; 
END
GO
```

Example :

```
EXECUTE [dbo].[GETLINKEDKEYS] 'Users', 32
```

| PrimaryTable | PrimaryTableColumn | PrimaryTableColumnID | ForeignTable | ForeignTableColumn | ForeignTableColumnID | ForeignTablePrimaryColumn | ForeignTablePrimaryColumnID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Users | UserID | 32 | UsersInfo | UserID | 32 | UsersInfoID | 123 |
| Users | UserID | 32 | Images | UserID | 32 | IamgeID | 56 |
| Users | UserID | 32 | UsersLogs | UserID | 32 | NULL | NULL |